# Is preparing instant coffee a brew?

Tags: brewing-process, instant

Preparing instant coffee is basically pouring hot water on dry coarse powder made out of a coffee drink.

Is it still called brewing?

It seems like a language shortcut, as the brew happened before making the instant coffee powder.

Answer (score 7):

I'd agree with you.  There isn't a brew happening because the solution was already created.  What you are performing is a rehydration.  However, "let me rehydrate some coffee" is a pretty awkward turn off phrase.

Comment: I just think instant coffee is a sin...

Comment: Not if it's Sanka and you're on the International space station, at that point, it's something off my bucket list.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question.  "When is instant coffee acceptable?" "In space."  I can think of brew methods that would work in zero-g.  However, the idea of near boiling water floating around in a compartment does sound a bit dangerous.